# WCF Exception Contract Missmatch , I don't think so

Tags: wcf, service, iis-8

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply this might be caused by
>   a contract mismath, a premature session shutdown or an internal server
>   error

Hey, I got an exception after calling a wcf service. I know this exception can get found a lot on stackoverflow, but I have a special behaviour. I also tried nearly all solution which are recommended, without success...

My project does the following: The module is like a normal chat, a wpf and asp usercontrol calls the service every 5 seconds and gets the online users. this normally worked fine on my windows 7 workstation. After I started to develope software on my new workstation with win 8 on it, I got this exception. The IIS Configuration are still the same. After the first user starts to frequently call the service everything works, until a second user calls the same service the exception above shows up. 
I set up a testmachine on win 7 and look what happens... Everything works again... I don't have a clue what to do ...

Service web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchName="Information, ActivityTracing"     propagateActivity="true">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="myUserTraceSource" switchName="Information, ActivityTracing">
    <listeners>
      <add name="xml" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="xml" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="hi5.PSA.ServiceLog.svclog" />
</sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
<appSettings>
<add key="Log4NetPath" value="config.log4net" />
</appSettings>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </assemblies>
</compilation>
<pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
<!-- that many MB should be enough :) -->
<httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPmiLookup" />
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="SolutionName.ChatService" behaviorConfiguration="chatServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" contract="SolutionName.contracts.Chat.IChatManager" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>        
    <behavior name="chatServiceBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"></modules>
 </system.webServer>
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MyEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Users.csdl|res://*/Users.ssdl|res://*/Users.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;&#xD;&#xA;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Client app.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsDualHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSDualHttpBinding_IChatManager" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true" algorithmSuite="Default" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsDualHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://localhost/SolutionName/ChatService.svc" binding="wsDualHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSDualHttpBinding_IChatManager" contract="hi5.medview.server.contracts.Chat.IChatManager" name="WSDualHttpBinding_ChatManager">
    <identity>
      <servicePrincipalName value="host/MyName"/>
    </identity>
  </endpoint>
</client>
```

Does anyone has any idea. The thing which makes me crazy is that, the service works fine for the first user who is calling it, but after a second user calls it, the damn thing doesn't work anymore...
Please help... 
Thx

Comment: Your web.config implies that your service uses default binding. From your client config, I can concur that you are using Message mode security. This definitely looks like a Binding Mismatch. Note, from the config, there is no way to figure out, why you are getting contract mismatch. Can you sync up the binding and test?